# Clone a demo website when new blog is created using WordPress Multisite

Tags: wordpress, clone, buddypress, multisite

I am presently working on a WordPress Multisite. Users can create a website by themselves, so there's no assistance from the admin on doing that.

When the user signs up, after they login, they can create a new website. Now, when they click the create button, I already have a demo website named `demo.mywebsite.com`. I want this website to be cloned for the new site created. So, when the user names the website fabrics, the site URL would be `fabrics.mywebsite.com`

My question is, how do I set-up the site so when a user creates a new website it automatically clones the demo website? Note that this happens at the frontend. I have seen a couple of plugins that allows the user to clone the website when on the dashboard, but in this scenario, it should happen automatically when the user creates the website from his frontend. The users are BuddyPress users.

Comment: look this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-clone-duplicator/ then you have to call the plugin duplication when a user create a website.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Any code snippet for that? I think this works from the dashboard which makes it a post-creation setup. I need something that auto-clones as the user clicks to create website

Comment: Yeah, it did. I'm sorry you have call my attention to it again. Thanks a bunch. That's what I'm using to create the function.